# how to send data from a stateless widget to stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a simple app in flutter where there are two widgets in main function. one is display text widget which is used to display text to the screen and another one is getting input from the user ie., TextField. this is simple. now i created a stateless widget sacaffold in main.dart and in the body i called two classes. one is 'textfield' stateless widget (as a separate dart file) and another is 'display' stateful widget (as a separate dart file) , since i wanted to update the display for every change in input textfield. now i get the setup and created textfield and send button in textfield.dart and i need to send that text to display_text.dart which has a stateful widget. how to do that. No Laughing pls.. new to programming and flutter.

```
  class TextFieldInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final txtController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: txtController,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Click Me'),
            onPressed: () {
              //want to send txtController.text to DisplayText (display_text.dart);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class DisplayText extends StatefulWidget {
  //DisplayText({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  _DisplayTextState createState() => _DisplayTextState();
}

class _DisplayTextState extends State<DisplayText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        'text from iput text fied here',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your data through navigator and access using widget object in stateful method.

i added the solution in following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldInput extends StatelessWidget {
    final txtController = TextEditingController();
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: txtController,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Click Me'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new DisplayText(text: txtController.text,)));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }


  class DisplayText extends StatefulWidget {
    String text;
      DisplayText({Key key,this.text}) : super(key: key);
    _DisplayTextState createState() => _DisplayTextState();
  }

  class _DisplayTextState extends State<DisplayText> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(
          widget.text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sending Text Between Flutter Widgets: Three Approaches
You're building a Flutter app with a TextField and a separate widget to display its input. How can you send the text from the TextField to the display widget?

Answer: Here are three approaches, with code snippets for each:

1. Route Parameters (Simple & Efficient):

(a) Sending:

```
// In TextField widget (e.g., TextFieldInput.dart)

onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/display', arguments: txtController.text);
}
```

(b) Receiving:

```
// In display widget (e.g., display_text.dart)

final text = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;

// Use 'text' in your Text widget
```

Advantages: Easy to implement, good for basic scenarios.

Disadvantages: Requires navigation, not ideal for frequent updates.

2. Provider Pattern (Stateful Management):

(a) Text Notifier:

```
// Separate file (e.g., text_notifier.dart)

class TextNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _text = "";

  String get text => _text;

  void updateText(String newText) {
    _text = newText;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

(b) Sending:

```
// In TextField widget (e.g., TextFieldInput.dart)

onPressed: () {
  widget.textNotifier.updateText(txtController.text);
}
```

(c) Receiving:

```
// In display widget (e.g., display_text.dart)

final textNotifier = ChangeNotifierProvider.of<TextNotifier>(context);

Text(
  textNotifier.text,
  // ...
)
```

Advantages: Centralized state management, good for frequent updates.

Disadvantages: More complex setup, might be overkill for simple cases.

3. Global Variable (Not Recommended):

```dart
// Not recommended for complex apps!

String globalText = "";

// Update and access 'globalText' in both widgets
```

Disadvantages: Tightly coupled code, difficult to maintain for larger apps.

Recommendation:

Choose Route Parameters for basic scenarios.
Use Provider Pattern for stateful communication and frequent updates.
Avoid Global Variables unless absolutely necessary.
Additional Tips:

Always handle null values when accessing text.
Use descriptive variable names and comments for clear code.
Consider state management solutions like Bloc or Riverpod for complex apps.