# Can bottomNavigationBar's `onTap` event be used to redraw a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn to use `BottomNavigationBar` (to replace buttons on the bottom of a screen). In my current code, when a user taps a Back button:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
     anotherObject.previousQuestion();
    },
  );
},
```

is triggered. The `previousQuestion` method changes the index in a list, and the screen is redrawn using info from the newly selected list item.

Can I make the same thing happen when a user taps a BottomNavigationBar?

My question arose because

- all the examples I saw focused on tab tapping to load different `body` widgets and
- in a MaterialApp, BottomNavigationBar is declared in the main app widget, which is stateless. And what I'm asking about involves changing the app's state. (The `onPressed` method above is currently called within a stateful widget.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in a MaterialApp, BottomNavigationBar is declared in the main app widget, which is stateless. And what I'm asking about involves changing the app's state. (The onPressed method above is currently called within a stateful widget.)

**Edit to clarify**: You can call any function from any widget with a trigger event `onTap`, `onPressed`, etc. If your widget does not have that property, you can wrap said widget with `InkWell`, or `GestureDetector`, for example.

> Can I make the same thing happen when a user taps a BottomNavigationBar?

Yes, you can. You can change virtually anything, as long as you can manipulate the Widget's state.

Comment: I'm unsure how to call a method in a `StatefulWidget` from within the stateless widget where BottomNavigationBar is declared. Or, alternatively, how to create `bottomNavigationBar` (which should always be visible) within a `StatefulWidget,' i.e., something other than the `Home` widget ... Hope that makes sense :-).

Comment: P.S. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761888/flutter-calling-setstate-from-other-widget?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487236/how-to-send-data-from-a-stateless-widget-to-stateful-widget?rq=1 appeared in the "Related" column after your response.

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm not particularly fond of those answers, I think those are being too complicated for what you want to achieve. An easier way to approach this would be using only stateless widgets and managing the state through `provider` or `scoped_model`.